# How many people could you take on in a fight?

Tags: planetside

A while back I played Planetside for a time. I remember sometimes not being able to get to a particular continent because the number of players on it was too high.

How many players were allowed on a continent at once? Was it an overall cap, or a cap of players per faction (e.g. to keep battles more even)? Basically, what was the maximum number of people your faction could be facing in a particular battle at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this wiki article](http://wiki.planetsidesyndicate.com/index.php?title=Population_lock), the number has changed multiple times, so it'd would depend on when you played.

---

Points from the article:

- In 2003 the population cap for an empire was 2/3rds total for a continent (total estimated around 500-550 players), leaving 1/3rd to split between the other two factions.
- In 2004 the population cap for an empire was reduced to 166 players.
- In 2005 the population cap for an empire was reduced to it's current 133 players.